# How to Change Post Variable Value in a AngularJS Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

I'm having two buttons, each button has ng-click event, the click event calls one method, the method has one argument.

I wish to pass the value of the argument to the Service Side via HTTP POST from AngularJS Controller.

The AngularJS Function CustomerGender(index), I wish to pass the index value to the Service.

```html
<div ng-app="Customer" ng-controller="CustomerCtrl">
    <button ng-click="CustomerGender('Male')">List of Male Customers</button>
    <button ng-click="CustomerGender('FeMale')">List of Female Customers</button>
</div>
```

The AngularJS Source Code:

> Note: The URL http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php is a
>   Sample URL

```
var CustomerApp = angular.module('Customer', []);
CustomerApp.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cacheFactory) {

    $scope.CustomerGender = function(index){

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php",
            data: {
                token: index
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
        request.success(function (response) 
        {
            $scope.data = response.records;
        });
    };
});
```

The Function is not working. If I set **token: 'Male'** directly, in Controller, then it pass the value to the Service, If i set **token: index**, then it can't pass the value to the Service. Kindly assist me.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Do you have any error messages from the console to share?

Comment: If I set token: 'Male', in Controller, then it pass the value to the Service, If i set token: index, then it can't pass the value to the Service.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use your code to post to the w3schools link it blocks the request. It seems to work fine when I try a different endpoint like `https://httpbin.org/post` though.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4jWWAh8cSEBlDb8Foeje) is a working plunker.